How do I refresh this macro when a value contained in a cell change?
I wrote this macro that filters the values contained in a table based on the dates entered in cells F2 (start date) and F1 (end date). I would like the macro to update automatically whenever the values contained in these cells change. How to do that?
This is the code I wrote
Sub FilterRawDataTableByDate()
    Dim wsRawData As Worksheet
    Dim wsLocked As Worksheet
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    
    Set wsRawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
    Set wsLocked = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Locked")
    
    startDate = CDate(wsLocked.Range("F2").Value)
    endDate = CDate(wsLocked.Range("F1").Value)

    wsRawData.ListObjects("RawDataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
End Sub


The Worksheet.Change event, or the Worksheet.Calculate event if these cells contain formulas.
